# flutter provider ChangeNotifier class with a call-back function not working

Tags: flutter, callback, flutter-provider

I'm using provider and my code looks like this.

```
class AbcClass with ChangeNotifier {


String abc1='111';
String abc2='222';



List<void Function(String)> get abcInputs {
    return [
      (newValue) => () {
            abc1 = newValue;
            notifyListeners();
          },
      (newValue) => () {
            abc2 = newValue;
            notifyListeners();
          }
    ];
  }


}
```

and i'm setting abcInputs(callback function) to UI textfield.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

context.watch<AbcClass>();
AbcClass abcClass= context.read<AbcClass>();
               

return TextFormField(
onChanged: abcClass.abcInputs[0],
initialValue:abcClass.abc1.toString(),

}
```

My problem is when i changed the input value from UI,
abcClass , abc1 value not change.
can anyone help to do that.
appreciate your help.

Comment: `abcClass` instance that you set in `initialValue` is using `context.read` . it will not rebuild not update. use `watch` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was ' => ' , when I removed it. it works

```
List<void Function(String)> get abcInputs {
    return [
      (newValue) => () {
            abc1 = newValue;
            notifyListeners();
          },
      (newValue) => () {
            abc2 = newValue;
            notifyListeners();
          }
    ];
  }
```

to this

```
   List<void Function(String)> get abcInputs {
        return [
          (newValue) () {
                abc1 = newValue;
                notifyListeners();
              },
          (newValue) () {
                abc2 = newValue;
                notifyListeners();
              }
        ];
      }
```